# Prevent artificial turf from getting lifted up by wind

Tags: wind, grass

My apartment has a balcony on the 4th floor of a building, which I covered with artificial turf to make it look nicer.

**The problem is that the wind lifts up and folds the artificial turf all the time**

[image]

[image]

[image]

To prevent this issue from happening, I have been thinking about the following solutions, and none seem adequate:

- **Gardening iron line** which I could pass through the turf holes (circled in red in above image) and attach to the balcony wooden boards, problem is that it wouldn't hold well to the boards (would probably slide out eventually)
- **Tablecloth clip** but I guess they will eventually rust (even those stainless ones aren't completely stainless)
- **Custom-made wooden casing**: covering the sides and holding the turf down. Seems like lots of work to setup and maintain (wood)

**What would you use to stopping the wind from lifting up/folding the turf?**

Comment: If the biggest concern with the wooden frame is the maintenance, you could always make it out of composite deck material (like Trex, but I assume other brands exist).  Looks like wood, but no chance of rot, no real upkeep.

Comment: Just put something weighty on the corners that tend to blow over.

Comment: try a staple gun or carpet glue, or 2-part epoxy; that stuff sticks everything...

Comment: @fixer1234: indeed I did that, but because I have very limited space on the balcony, I'd like to avoid reducing space even more

Comment: Can you use a staple gun?

Comment: It seems there are several recommendations with the glue. The problem is that once a year the wood has to be treated, so if the gras is stuck to it that's not good.